# recover data from Huawei G610-U20 boot loop

Tags: boot-loop, huawei

My phone is stuck in boot loop, I think because not enough memory (RAM) is available to start the updated version of Android. In fact, after upgrading Android in 2021 the boot loop appeared, and then after 30 mins of loop the phone would finally start. This happened a few times, before I upgraded again and it's been stuck in boot loop ever since. On my computer, I have noticed that androidx86 is stuck in boot when not enough RAM is available, therefore I deduce this might be the cause. Internal storage should not be full on my phone...

I could try and downgrade the Android version, because I can't think of any other ways to access the internal storage (either by disassembly or by alternative boot options).

I can start recovery mode POWER + VOL+, however if I press VOL- + POWER, then only one line of microscopic writing appears on the bottom of the screen, and it's impossible to decipher what is written.

Wiping cache does not help. Firmware download mode accessible. As far as I remember: Not rooted, USB debugging enabled.

Any help to find some way and recover my data from the internal storage? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you think that the installed upgrade has "not enough memory (RAM)"? Official updates you receive from Huawei are usually well tested so that they fit to your hardware. Or may be you wanted to say "Flash memory" and your internal flash memory was almost full when installing the update? (RAM is not Flash memory).

Comment: I've added details to my question!